# What happens to unique_ptr after std::move()?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

This code is what I want to do:

```
Tony& Movie::addTony()
{
    Tony *newTony = new Tony;
    std::unique_ptr<Tony> tony(newTony);
    attachActor(std::move(tony));
    return *newTony;
}
```

I am wondering if I could do this instead:

```
Tony& Movie::addTony()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Tony> tony(new Tony);
    attachActor(std::move(tony));
    return *tony.get();
}
```

But will `*tony.get()` be the same pointer or null? I know I could verify, but what is the standard thing for it to do?

Comment: Why are you `move()`'ing the `unique_ptr` into `attachActor()` to begin with? What does `attachActor()` actually do?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

No, you cannot do that instead. Moving the `unique_ptr` nulls it. If it didn't, then it would not be unique. I am of course assuming that `attachActor` doesn't do something silly like this:

```
attachActor(std::unique_ptr<Tony>&&) {
    // take the unique_ptr by r-value reference,
    // and then don't move from it, leaving the
    // original intact
}
```

Section 20.8.1 paragraph 4.

> Additionally, u (the unique_ptr object) can, upon request, transfer
>   ownership to another unique pointer u2. Upon completion of such a
>   transfer, the following postconditions hold:
>      -- u2.p is equal to the pre-transfer u.p,
>      -- **u.p is equal to nullptr**, and
>      -- if the pre-transfer u.d maintained state, such state has been transferred to u2.d.

Comment: Though, it's probably not a great idea to have a function that takes `unique_ptr&&` anyway (aside from move-constructor and move-assigners).

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, thank you for the answer! Yeah, attachActor() takes std::unique_ptr<Tony>, nothing fancy.

Comment: @Rufflewind Not necessary, it might be handy if the function can throw and you don't want to lose the object you passed to it.  Basically every container `insert`/`push_back` function.

Answer (score 21):

The standard says (§ 20.8.1.2.1 ¶ 16, emphasis added) that the move constructor of `std::unique_ptr`

> ```
> unique_ptr(unique_ptr&& u) noexcept;
> ```
>
> Constructs a `unique_ptr` by **transferring ownership** from `u` to `*this`.

Therefore, after you move-construct the temporary object that gets passed as argument to `attachActor` form your `tony`, `tony` no longer owns the object and hence `tony.get() == nullptr`. (This is one of the few cases where the standard library actually makes assertions about the state of a moved-away-from object.)

However, the desire to return the reference can be fulfilled without resorting to naked `new` and raw pointers.

```
Tony&
Movie::addTony()
{
  auto tony = std::make_unique<Tony>();
  auto p = tony.get();
  attachActor(std::move(tony));
  return *p;
}
```

This code assumes that `attachActor` will not drop its argument on the floor. Otherwise, the pointer `p` would dangle after `attachActor` has `return`ed. If this cannot be relied upon, you'll have to re-design your interface and use shared pointers instead.

```
std::shared_ptr<Tony>
Movie::addTony()
{
  auto tony = std::make_shared<Tony>();
  attachActor(tony);
  return tony;
}
```

Comment: Transfer of ownership does not imply that `u` does not own anything, only that it does no longer own the object it owned before. If this was the only requirement, the transfer could happen by just **swapping** object ownership between `u` and `*this` (which is what some other move constructors do to prevent any allocation and deallocation). But as Benjamin Lindley notes, there are additional requirements on std::unique_ptr beyond just the textual "transferring ownership".

Answer (score 4):

After `move`, `unique_ptr`s are set to `nullptr`. Finally, I think it depends on what `attachActor` is doing, however, in many cases, a good approach would be to use *move semantics* to guarantee single ownership for Tony at all times which is a way to reduce the risks of some types of bugs. My idea is to try to mimic ownership and borrowing from [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/).

```cpp
    #include <string>
    #include <memory>
    #include <vector>
    #include <iostream>
    
    
    using namespace std;
    
    class Tony {
        public:
            string GetFullName(){
                return "Tony " + last_name_;
            }
            void SetLastName(string lastname) {
                last_name_ = lastname;
            }
        private:
            string last_name_;
    };
    
    class Movie {
        public:
            unique_ptr<Tony> MakeTony() {
                auto tony_ptr = make_unique<Tony>();
                auto attached_tony_ptr = AttachActor(move(tony_ptr));
                return attached_tony_ptr;
            }
            vector<string> GetActorsList(){
                return actors_list_;
            }
    
        private:
            unique_ptr<Tony> AttachActor(unique_ptr<Tony> tony_ptr) {
                tony_ptr->SetLastName("Garcia");
                actors_list_.push_back(tony_ptr->GetFullName());
                return tony_ptr;   // Implicit move
            }
    
            vector<string> actors_list_;
    };
    
    
    int main (int argc, char** argv) {
        auto movie = make_unique<Movie>();
        auto tony = movie->MakeTony();
        cout << "Newly added: " << tony->GetFullName() << endl;
        for(const auto& actor_name: movie->GetActorsList()) {
            cout << "Movie actors: " << actor_name << endl;
        }
    }
```