# Defining destructor of base class makes std::map::emplace fail

Tags: c++, c++11

When I try to emplace an object which has a unique_ptr and a destructor into a map, I get a compiler error, shown below. However, when the object has no destructor defined, emplacement works just fine. What is going on?

How can I emplace an object which has a unique_ptr and a destructor defined into a map?

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct A {
    std::string name;
    std::unique_ptr<int> p;
    virtual ~A(){};  // comment out this line
    A(std::string n) : name(n) { }
};
int main()
{
    std::map<int, A> m;
    m.emplace(1, A("Name"));
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using Apple clang version 11.0.0 on OSX

**Compiler Error**

```
In file included from main.cpp:1:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/map:480:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__tree:16:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:1826:31: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::__1::pair<const int, B>'
            ::new((void*)__p) _Up(_VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
                              ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:1718:18: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::__value_type<int, B>, void *> >::construct<std::__1::pair<const int, B>, int, B>' requested here
            {__a.construct(__p, _VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);}
                 ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:1561:14: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::__1::allocator_traits<std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::__value_type<int, B>, void *> > >::__construct<std::__1::pair<const int, B>,
      int, B>' requested here
            {__construct(__has_construct<allocator_type, _Tp*, _Args...>(),
             ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__tree:2212:20: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::__1::allocator_traits<std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::__value_type<int, B>, void *> > >::construct<std::__1::pair<const int, B>,
      int, B>' requested here
    __node_traits::construct(__na, _NodeTypes::__get_ptr(__h->__value_), _VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
                   ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__tree:2157:29: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::__1::__tree<std::__1::__value_type<int, B>, std::__1::__map_value_compare<int, std::__1::__value_type<int, B>, std::__1::less<int>, true>,
      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__value_type<int, B> > >::__construct_node<int, B>' requested here
        __node_holder __h = __construct_node(_VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
                            ^

... [similar error messages come here]

main.cpp:19:11: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::map<int, B, std::__1::less<int>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const
      int, B> > >::emplace<int, B>' requested here
        m.emplace(1, B("Name"));
      ^
```

Comment: [Defining a destructor causes the implicit move constructor to not be generated](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor#Implicitly-declared_move_constructor)

Comment: [What happens to unique_ptr after std::move()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36071220/what-happens-to-unique-ptr-after-stdmove)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::map::emplace` allows to create object in place by passing `constructor's arguments` and you don't need copy/move.
As mentions in one of comment that because of user provided distructor, compiler does not generate move constructor implicitly.
But i have added move because otherwise it not useful any way in real world problems.

Due to this you need to create object in place.

Using following code.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <map>
#include <memory>

struct A {
    std::string name;
    std::unique_ptr<int> p;
    ~A(){}
    A(std::string n) : name(n) { }
    A(A&& other): name(std::move(other.name)), p(std::move(other.p)){}
};

int main(int , char *[]){

std::map<int, A> m;
    m.emplace(1, "Name");

    for(const auto& e: m)
        cout<< e.first<< ", "<< e.second.name<<'\n';
}
```

output: `1, Name`

Comment: This answer would be more helpful if it included an explanation of what was wrong with OP's code, and how this fixes the problem.

Comment: @0x5453, Added explanation.

Comment: Thanks! And what if the constructor of A has more than one argument? Which is the case in my real world code. Your solution seems to fail for me, when I have more than one constructor argument. In that case I would have to define a move constructor? Or could I use something like `m.emplace(1, {"name"})` ?

Comment: @0x5453: Sorry about this, just put the solution and didn't thing about future problem. But thanks to remind.